# qsort endless loop causes error C

Tags: c, infinite-loop, qsort

So I´m stuck with this sort function because everything seems to work fine when I debug it and there are no errors or warnings what so ever but it somehow gets stuck in an infinite loop.

My struct(if it helps):

```
typedef struct raeume{
char number[5];
char klasse[6];
int tische;
}raeume;
```

my start of the qsort function:

```
void ausgabesortiert(struct raeume *arr[],int used,int size)
{
    qsort(*arr,size,sizeof(raeume),cmp);
    ausgabesortiert(arr,size,used);
}
```

my compare function:

```
int cmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    raeume *raumA = (raeume *) a;
    raeume *raumB = (raeume *) b;
    int tempA = raumA->klasse[0] - '0';
    int tempB = raumB->klasse[0] - '0';
    if(tempA < tempB)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(tempA > tempB)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(tempA == tempB)
    {
        if(raumA->tische > raumB->tische)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(raumA->tische < raumB->tische)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(raumA->tische == raumB->tische)
        {
           return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: the `cmp` function could be simpler as two of the tests are quite unnecessary (the 2 equality tests). The function only needs 4 tests, with a final `return 0` which currently is never executed. None of the `else`s are necessary either.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah your right thank you!

Comment: And while I am nit-picking, the `cmp` function could be slightly quicker by removing the `- '0'` from each initialisation - you will still be making valid comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of your `ausgabesortiert` function

```
void ausgabesortiert(struct raeume *arr[],int used,int size)
```

clearly suggests that array `arr` contains *pointers* to `struct raeume` objects, not the objects themselves.

But the call to `qsort`

```
qsort(*arr,size,sizeof(raeume),cmp);
```

and the comparison function are written as if you are trying to sort an array of `struct raeume` objects themselves that begins at `arr[0]` location.

While there's nothing formally invalid in this, it still looks rather strange. Is this really your intent? What exactly are you trying to sort, again? The `arr` array or some other array pointed by `arr[0]`? I suspect that it is the former, in which case you need to fix the `qsort` call and comparison function.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that.